# Linux Kernel and Open Source developers sources of income

Tags: career-development

don't get me wrong: i like the majestic Linux Kernel project and all the Open Source community but my question is really straightforward:
How do i live if i become a full time Linux Kernel Developer?
If i've got a 9 to 5 job as a programmer on another private company i cannot sit in front of a pc all night long tinkering with the kernel code. But if i quit my job and i become a full time kernel developer i'll be poor soon.

I am missing something?

Comment: "How do i live if i become a full time Linux Kernel Developer?" - Is this your question? Because it seems wildly unrelated to this StackExchange.

Comment: More or less...

Comment: Fair enough, but I still don't see how we can answer this. Maybe you should perform a survey of Linux Kernel Developers, and ask how they live. It seems to have little to nothing to do with any Workplace issue.

Comment: The Linux Foundation has a report which may answer your question (i.e. who is sponsoring Linux kernel development) http://www.linuxfoundation.org/publications/linux-foundation/who-writes-linux-2015

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: The Free Software Manifesto's answer -- Richard Stallman's original statement of purpose before there even was a Free Software Foundation -- was that "software should be free, support should cost." In other words, he felt you should take your profit from being enough of an expert in Gnu's guts and usage that you can hire yourself out to companies which need that expertise. If that means you flip back and forth between free and paid work, so be it.

Comment: Or you get lucky and find a company that wants to productize the free code or use it to drive industry standards and is willing to contribute your work to Apache or whatever in order to achieve that... which I spent a decade or so doing on the Xerces and Xalan projects. (And BSF, come to think of it.) But that's _very_ rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i live if i become a full time Linux Kernel Developer? If i've
>   got a 9 to 5 job as a programmer on another private company i cannot
>   sit in front of a pc all night long tinkering with the kernel code.
>   But if i quit my job and i become a full time kernel developer i'll be
>   poor soon.
>
> I am missing something?

Yes. You are missing the fact that some companies hire people to be Linux Kernel Developers.

Do a quick search on job boards or Google, and you'll find some. Perhaps in your part of the world, and with your background/experience.